# get timestamp using OracleCachedRowSet

Tags: java, oracle

Code :

```
 OracleCachedRowSet rowSet =  new OracleCachedRowSet();             
 ResultObject obj = new ResultObject(0,null);      
 PreparedStatement pstat = connection.prepareStatement(strQry);
 rowSet.populate(pstat.executeQuery());
 rowSet.beforeFirst();

 while(rowSet.next()){
      System.out.println("Conference name "+rowSet.getString(1));
      System.out.println("StartTime "+rowSet.getTimestamp(5)) ;
 }
```

When i run above code i got error like :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
    at oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleCachedRowSet.getTimestamp(OracleCachedRowSet.java:4399)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:102)
```

Same thing is working fine(check below correct code) if i use `ResultSet` instead of `OracleCachedRowSet`

```
  PreparedStatement pstat = connection.prepareStatement(strQry);                    
  ResultSet rset =   pstat.executeQuery();                  
  while(rset.next()){
        System.out.println("Conference name "+rset.getString(1));
        System.out.println("StartTime "+rset.getTimestamp(5)) ;
  }
```

Is there any way to `getTimestamp()` using `OracleCachedRowSet` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve defined things by :

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date(((oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP)rSet.getObject(5)).timestampValue().getTime())
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
Object timeStampObj = result.getObject(2);
if (timeStampObj instanceof oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP){
    oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP oraTimeStamp = (oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP)timeStampObj;
    report.setLastRefresh(new Timestamp(oraTimeStamp.longValue()));
}
```

Here result is an instance of OracleCachedRowSet and setLastRefresh of report instance takes Timestamp.  My previous code was:

```
report.setLastRefresh(result.getTimestamp(2));
```

The above line worked in Tomcat, but not WebSphere throwing "Invalid column type" exception.